# ons.navigator.pushPage not working with PhoneGap geolocation

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

When i use ons.navigator.pushPage and navigate to searchNearby html page it should show me current geolocation coordinates. However it doesnt do that. when i load the searchNearby page directly it shows coordinates that perfectly. Any idea about it

**index.html**

```
<body ng-controller="courseController">

<ons-navigator title="Class Finder">
<ons-page>
<ons-row>
    <ons-col size="80" style="padding: 8px">
    <ons-search-input ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search..." >
    </ons-search-input>
    </ons-col>
    <ons-col size="20" >
    <ons-button type="large--quiet" ng-click="ons.navigator.pushPage('searchNearby/index.html',{title:'Search Nearby'})">Search nearby
    </ons-button>
    </ons-col>
</ons-row>
</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
</body>
```

**searchNearby/index.html**

```
<body>
<p id="geolocation">Finding geolocation...</p>
<div id="t01"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var lat,lon;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    }
    function onSuccess(position) {

    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');

    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude  + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + position.timestamp                    + '<br />';

}
function onError(error){
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
</script>   
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is not getting fired on searchNearby/index.html because you page is being loaded asynchronously.

I would suggest setting up some kind of callback for when then page has fully loaded, so you can execute your getCurrentPosition method.

Alternatively, you could get the position beforehand and then pass the success object over to the searchNearby page.